# Android studio Project Using LocationListener and LocationManager doesn't seem to run

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, locationlistener

I wrote and compiled the program below and ran it but the intended purpose, which is to display the speed to a `textView` doesn't function as far as i can tell from running it on my phone. 
There are two location output variables, `speed`, and `ourSpe` because `ourSpe` came from a youtube video I watched and it didn't work, and `speed` comes from a stack overflow question I looked up. Both helped but neither is getting a result to print out ass I press the Button `spedButt`. I think I just wrote the code in the wrong order but I'm also not sure if I'm in using `LocationManager` right.

The layout file only has two `textViews` and a `Button` in a `Relativelayout`but stack overflow keeps giving me an error and I can't figure that one out either. I'm having a bad day.

Main Code

```
    package com.example.vitaliy_2.safespeedalert;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;



    public class SpeedTest extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
            TextView txt;
            TextView txt_2;
            Button spedButt;
            float curSpe;
            float speed;
            Location l;
            Location mLastLocation;
            Location pCurrentLocation;

    @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed_test);



         txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed_display);
            txt_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed_display_2);
            spedButt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spedButt);
            speed = 0;

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {return;}
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            this.onLocationChanged(null);

        }



        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            l = location;
            if (this.mLastLocation != null)
                speed = (float )Math.sqrt(
                        Math.pow(pCurrentLocation.getLongitude() - mLastLocation.getLongitude(), 2)
                                + Math.pow(pCurrentLocation.getLatitude() - mLastLocation.getLatitude(), 2)
                ) / (pCurrentLocation.getTime() - this.mLastLocation.getTime());
            this.mLastLocation = pCurrentLocation;



            spedButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(l == null){
                        txt.setText("-.- m/s");
                        txt_2.setText("-.- m/s");

                    }else{
                        if (pCurrentLocation.hasSpeed())


   speed = pCurrentLocation.getSpeed();
                    curSpe = location.getSpeed();

                    String sent = speed + "m/s";
                    txt.setText(sent);
                    String sentTwo = curSpe + "m/s";
                    txt_2.setText(sentTwo);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: did you request the location permission ?? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Yes @Budius. I It's in the code I posted as well as in the manifest. I did find it weird that the dialog never popped up but the program never game me a runtime error.

Comment: the code you posted only checks IF you have permission (r which apparently you don't) when the IF fails you have to request it. I'm kinda out of time to write for you here, but check again the docs, it's certainly missing it

Comment: thank you @Budius, I figured it out. I assumed that The code that self-filled was enough.

Comment: @Budius, would you know why when the permission pops up for the location and I accept it the location icon in the quick settings button doesn't light up? I keep reading but nothing I've found mentions this.

Comment: because AFTER you accept the permission you have to request the location updates. When you successfuly request, then it should come up the indicator. You have to `@Override` the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method. Again, check the documentation that it explains there how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering My own question, This code pops up automatically but there still needs to be a clause that asks for permission.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


        return;
    }else{
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, this);
    }
    this.onLocationChanged(null);
```